# Perl - opening a file in binary with final character 0x1A/EOF/Ctrl-Z

Tags: perl, cygwin

I have inherited some old perl code with the following comment and code. I *strongly* suspect the comment is both outdated and only refered to operation under Windows anyway, but I'd like to be certain.

This code

```perl
open($fh, "+<" . $filename) || die "...";
binmode($fh)
```

Was replaced with this code with the following comment.

```perl
## Open the (existing) file for writing to. Use sysopen so we can specify O_BINARY on open, otherwise
## we lose the final char of the file if it happens to be 0x1A (ctrl-Z)
sysopen( $fh, $filename, O_RDWR | O_BINARY ) || dbgdie("couldn't open the file: $filename");
```

I suspect that this statement is very very old and reflects behaviour under cygwin a long time ago. (It was cygwin 1.5 on Windows XP back then.) Cygwin is now no longer used at all. But I want to understand the root cause of the message, to know if I can remove it.

It's hard to "prove a negative", if I can't reproduce the original problem, does it mean that it's now fixed or simply that my testcase isn't quite right? So ideally somebody with a long memory can give some history here and background.

**Update**
As @ikegami and others point out, there was a known Windows interaction where 0x1A was interpreted as EOF and file reading would stop there. That is a known historical fact. That is surely a factor/related here. Without more information on the original bug my codebase was working around I can't tell if that's the whole story, or if there was a subtler variation on the 0x1A behavior at play (which is what I suspect). In any case, it seems pretty clear that the issue is long gone.

Comment: Seems to be a non-issue since a long time - see https://github.com/perl/perl5/issues/7122

Comment: This has nothing to do with `Cygwin`. It is a relic of early versions `MS-DOS` which did not have a text I/o mode, so you had to mark the end of a text file with ctrl-z. Later versions, and language runtimes could write text files without the ctrl-z,. This kind of code persists for backward compatibility. When PCs arrived, `*nix` code had to support this for interoperability. The `don't fix it if it ain't broke` adage applies here.

Answer (score 3):

Back in the DOS days, 0x1A would signal the end of a text file. Encountering 0x1A in text mode would signal EOF just as if the last byte had been read, no matter how many bytes actually remained in the file. I don't know if it was the OS or I/O libraries. I suspect it was the former initially, but it later became emulated by I/O libraries (for backwards compatibility). In any case, Windows does not do this anymore, and Perl does not appear to do this anymore either.

Yet, you should still use binary mode for non-text files. You don't need to use `sysopen` to do that, though. You can use either of the following:

```perl
open( my $fh, '+<:raw', $qfn )
   or die( ... );
```

or

```perl
open( my $fh, '+<', $qfn )
   or die( ... );

binmode( $fh );
```

- This prevents CR ⇔ CRLF translation on Windows.
- This prevents the addition of encoding layers (e.g. provided by `use open`).

And in the extremely unlikely possibility that 0x1A is still significant somewhere,

- This prevents any character from being perceived as indicating EOF.

Comment: Thanks. I was actually aware of most of that. The comment seemed to mention a very special corner-case where the final char is 0x1a and in that case it is lost. This seems distinct from the "if there is a 0x1a anywhere in the file, reading will stop there" situation.

Comment: It stopped reading at 1A, whether it's at the end or not

Comment: Absolutely, I'm not denying that that was a behavior in the past. But in this case, a `open(fh); binmode(fh)` was specifically replaced by `sysopen(...O_BINARY)` with the comment that there was a problem if 0x1A was the *last* character.  Yes, perhaps the comment was wrong, but this is a highly-skilled low-level embedded SW developer whom I trust.

Comment: I've clarified my original question to be more clear. I do appreciate the answers.

Comment: Re "*perhaps the comment was wrong*", The comment wasn't wrong. It signaled EOF when the last byte of the file like the comment says. As I've repeatedly stated, it meant EOF anywhere. That includes as the last byte of the file.

Comment: Yes and no. This developer would likely have written "0x1A anywhere in the file", not "0x1A at the end of the file" if that's what he meant. Although yes, a 0x1A anywhere in the file would have, through this bug, rendered that the effective end of the file. Does your understanding of the issue jibe with the observation that the problem was there with `open($fh); binmode($fh)` but resolved with `sysopen($fh ... O_BINARY)`?

Comment: Look, I've already told you the dev's problem no longer exists, and the more idiomatic way to solve related problems. And I'm tired of repeating myself.

Comment: I appreciate your replies (and more generally your great help on SO and Permonks and elsewhere) and I'm not trying to be difficult. I agree, the problem is surely fixed since the EOF behaviour is no longer in Windows anyway. But if I break my product because "well, a similar-but-not-exactly-the-same problem was fixed so I assumed they are the same", then I'll get that whole lecture about "when you assume..." I still suspect that the original problem was an interesting corner-case variation on this.

Comment: Re "*a similar-but-not-exactly-the-same problem was fixed*", No, the very problem mentioned in the comment was fixed. I've told you this repeatedly. At this point, you're just spamming.

Comment: We'll just have to agree to disagree then.

Comment: If someone says "Google Maps doesn't display my street name correctly because it contains an acute accent". If I tell you that Google Maps was fixed to handles accents correctly, do you agree the problem was fixed? That's exactly the situation here.

Comment: Re "*We'll just have to agree to disagree then*", *shurg* You can disagree all you want, but 1A wasn't just special at the end of the file. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file), this is for backwards compatibility with CP/M where files had to be a multiple of 128 bytes in size. (So if the real size was 20, you'd have 107 bytes following the 1A.)